# What would you say my fach could be?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, tenor

I know you've already seen loads of this but I think I might need professional advice, none is available where I am.

I am 17, I have a very full and resonant low register. I can give a loud D2. My lowest note is a C#2. I'm not exactly good at belting, my technique is not the best, I often opt for a mix (is that bad?). My highest belt is a G4 but (suprisingly I think), I can mix up to E5, my highest falsetto is a B5 and my passagio points are at C4 and F#4. My voice is light at my upper range, almost feminine but ny lower range is deeper much like a bass. I'm more comfortable at my upper range (G#3-F4) but sound better at my mid-lower range (C3-A3).

I'm a contemporary singer and I think it would really help if I could know my fach. Am I a lyric tenor? Lyric baritone or even a bass-baritone? Or is it even necessary for me to know?

Not sure if this matters but I can hit an F6 on whistle tone

Comment: Why is it necessary to know? To me, it's academic, and may well change over the next few years anyhow. Were you to join a choir, you may be asked the question, but the choirmaster will be *far* more interested in what you sing like, than your fach. Any answers will be particularly with reference to you, so won't be of much help to future readers.

Comment: So sorry for the irrelevant question, I'm just a little desperate, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder why the Sports stacks exchange does not get a deluge of people posting their thigh measurements and asking what running distance they should focus on.

And that's a completely one-dimensional endeavor where in the end it only counts whether you make some time or not.

In contrast, a singing career is not about whether you can hit some note or not.  It's about how you integrate what you are working with into a coherent and a compelling package.

You write: "I think I might need professional advice, none is available where I am."

That's all you need to know.  There is no way whatsoever that making choices for a fach makes any sense at all when there is no professional education available.

In particular since you are 17, with your larynx just having had a growth spurt and not yet being hardened out.  Harboring delusions about your purported fach and straining your voice according to self-imagined goals in the absence of any useful point of comparison is a recipe for ruining your voice to the point where any professional career where a fach would be of relevance would be preposterous.  Popular music, in contrast, can monetise even voices in various state of ruin.

If you want to work with voice programs on your own, don't focus on extending your range.  Instead focus on increasing the quality of what you can navigate with reasonable comfort and work on blending your registers where what you have is consistently workable, pleasant, and expressive.

Comment: A nice first answer! Maybe not what OP wants to hear, but to the point nevertheless. +1.

Comment: I'm grateful for this but what do I do now that there's no professional music teacher anywhere around me. I'm a little skeptical about online music classes, I've searched but can't find any. It's almost frustrating. I'm really grateful for the advice but what do you suggest I do without harming my voice in the long run?

Comment: @Ifeoluwa Online lessons are certainly only a fraction as useful as in-person... but much, much better than nothing. My daughter took piano last year from someone in another country. I'm sure the market is wide-open now to inferior teachers online, but it should be possible to find good ones. Your best bet is to start with institutions that have an established reputation to protect, like well-known music schools. You could simply look up voice faculty at major conservatories and email them; full professors are might be too busy, but their students would be highly skilled.